# Possible to click through a control?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have two controls that overlap, the top one contains transparency.

Whenever the top control is **clicked/hovered**, I would like that the bottom control also receives the same messages (`WM_MOUSEMOVE`, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, etc).

To 'partially' achieve this, I'm sub-classing the top control handling `WM_NCHITTEST` and returning `-1`:

```
// HTTRANSPARENT
// -1
// In a window currently covered by another window
// in the same thread(the message will be sent to
// underlying windows in the same thread until one
// of them returns a code that is not HTTRANSPARENT).
case WM_NCHITTEST:    
{
    //...
    return -1;    
}
```

This makes mouse/click messages to be sent to the bottom control.

However, the top control doesn't receive any message.

Is there any other way to make a control 'click through' and it still receive the messages?

Comment: You get to handle mouse input at most once. There is no second chance.

Comment: You could forward the mouse messages from the top control to the bottom control.

Comment: @zett42 Forward you mean replicate them using PostMessage?

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). Same principles apply to mouse input. In addition, you'll lose the value returned from `GetMessageTime` or `GetMessageExtraInfo`.

Comment: @IInspectable Correct, although using `SendInput` wouldn't help here, as it doesn't allow to specify the target window. If OP would explain what he actually wants to achieve, we could possibly suggest a more robust solution, rather than solving an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: It's hard to say overlapped controls are not a problem. You may explain what you actually want to achieve.